# select todays date to get the record

Tags: mysql

I am writing a cron job that will need to pull out the current days records. In my table I have a column called modify_date which is a unix time stamp, in format of `1/29/2011 9:59:47 AM`

What would be the sql for the current date so it chooses the date part only and give current dats results accordingly.
thanks

Comment: Dare I say... read the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1  WHERE DATE(modify_date) = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a check

```
   WHERE data > '1/29/2011 00:00:01' and date < '1/29/2011 23:59:59'
```